# How does "and eax,80000000h "in assembly work?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have an assembly program:

```
move eax, op1;
AND eax, 80000000h;
jz l1;
```

This program checks if `op1` is positive or negative.
How does comparing `eax` to `80000000h` check is `op1` is negative or positive?

Comment: The more common way how to test it is to use non-destructive test (in your example the copy of `op1` value in `eax` is destroyed by the `and`. There's x86 instruction called `TEST` (deja vu?), which will execute `AND` of the operands, setting flag registers according to the result, but the result itself is thrown away (not stored). In your example: `mov eax,op1` `test eax,eax` `jz zero` `jns positive` `js negative` will do the sign/nosign test while keeping the copy of op1 in eax, and also without the constant (as all the negative numbers have 0x80000000 bit set)

Answer (score 4):

Values in registers are stored in two's-complement format, and the highest bit corresponds to the negative sign. The constant `80000000h` corresponds to highest bit set in binary value of `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`. Applying `and` with it to the register `eax` results in non-zero if and only if the highest bit of `eax` is set, that is, the number stored in `eax` is negative. The conditional jump is not triggered in this case. It results in zero if the top bit is not set, that is, if the value is non-negative (0 or positive), and that triggers the `jz` conditional jump.